# Why is `paredit-kill` (`C-k`) not working in the minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer, minor-mode, paredit

This is [my config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el). I frequently use `C-k` which is bounded to `paredit-kill`.

In general, it works. However, it does **not** work when I am typing in the minibuffer. For instance, after executing `C-x C-f` (bounded to `counsel-find-file`), I can start typing something, then execute `C-a` moving the cursor to the beginning, and `C-k` does not work as expected, since it does not delete text.

Why is `paredit-kill` not working on the mini-buffer?

Obs.: I am using this on MacOS.

Comment: I don't use use paredit, so I'm not sure what `C-k` does. But my educated guess says it does the same that `C-M-k` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the minibuffer's major mode is `minibuffer-mode` which has a different keymap than whatever mode you are using for the "normal" buffer. You could try (but you shouldn't - DAMHIKT) enabling `paredit-mode` in the usual way in your minibuffer - like this:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-mode-hook #'paredit-mode)
```

The problem with that is that the minor mode keymap (i.e. `paredit-mode-map` in this case) would shadow the major mode keymap (i.e. `minibuffer-mode-map` in this case), and since the minor mode keymap binds things like `RET`, it would wreak havoc on the minibuffer's operations; e.g. `RET` is bound to `minibuffer-complete-and-exit` in the `minibuffer-mode` keymap but if you enable the minor mode, it would be bound to `paredit-RET`, a different function that knows nothing about the minibuffer or how to exit it.

You might want to try selectively modifying the major mode keymap to modify just the `C-k` binding (which, incidentally, is *not* defined in this keymap: it is picked up from the global map - see [Active keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html) in the Elisp Reference manual):

```el
(define-key minibuffer-mode-map (kbd "C-k") #'paredit-kill)
```

or you can, if you want, redefine it in `global-map` so that any mode that does not define it on its own, will pick it up from the global map (however, if it it *does* define it on its own, then you'll have to do some digging to find out *which* map you have to modify).